# Changing time zone after connecting to database using "set time_zone = ..."

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, timezone

I'm trying to change the time zone to "Europe/London" right after connecting to my database. This was my original code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampletable', 'exampleuser', 'examplepassw', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  'SET NAMES utf8');
```

And I changed it into the following code but apparently that's not the right way to change the time zone cause I get an error.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampletable', 'exampleuser', 'examplepassw', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  'SET NAMES utf8', 'SET time_zone = 'Europe/London''));
```

How can I change the time zone starting from PDO?

Comment: I for one don't know if it's possible to inject it into PDO, but  `<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` not sufficient or adequate?

Comment: See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48859 might be some answers in there for you. Are using `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8;SET time_zone = 'Europe/Prague'")` so give that a try.

Comment: What error do you get? I see several potential problems with the code. (a) The value needs to be an array, (b) A single quoted string inside a single quoted string. (c) SET time_zone may be per statement, and (d) timezone names may not be available to your MySQL server.  Try `array (\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => array ('SET NAMES utf8', 'SET GLOBAL time_zone = "+01:00"'))`.

Comment: `'SET NAMES utf8', "SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'"));` and now, we wait...

Comment: So now I have this code and I my webpage won't load anymore: `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampletable', 'exampleuser', 'examplepassw', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => array ('SET NAMES utf8', "SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'")));`

Comment: Then I suggest you try my first suggestion. `<?php date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); // rest of code` - Other than that, I've no other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This works: `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampletable', 'exampleuser', 'examplepassw', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8;SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'"));`

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. *Cheers* - You're welcome. Finally got resolved :)

Answer (score 11):

With some help of others (see comments), I managed to find the code that does the job:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampletable', 
               'exampleuser', 
               'examplepassw', 
               [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8;SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this (on Amazon RDS - since there is no 'system' way to change it):

```
try {
    $timezone = "America/Chicago";;

    $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database', 'username', 'password');
    $objDb->exec("SET time_zone = '{$timezone}'");

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way that works for me:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.';dbname='.$dbname,$username,$password,
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8, time_zone = "-6:00";', 
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

Hope this help to you.

Comment: any reason you are setting the charset through a query, not DSN?

Comment: No reason in particular. I work with Latin characters and think is the best way.

Comment: It is not. As per documentation, setting charset in the DSN is the only recommended way as it tells both serer  *and* client which charset is used, while your query affects the server only