# Unable to Set MySQL Timezone using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> Duplicate marked link address the part "how to configure time zone?", I
>   followed the same but it gives me an error as explained below

I am seeing following error on my php page

```
Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

I have gone throught multiple questions of same nature, but unable to understand the problem in my specific case.

Here is the query I am trying to run

```
SELECT  count(*) as total FROM  my_company en
                ORDER BY  cmpid ASC
```

**Note:** This is the first query, no query before this one is executed. I though I might be missing `$stmt->closeCursor();` but that is not the case.

However I do have made some change to set database time zone
My code work fine for following code

```
$pdo = new PDO ( "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password );
```

I wanted to achieve following thing (setting time zone of mysql)

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = 'UTC';SET NAMES utf8 ;");
```

So for `PDO` I made following change and now my code does not work.

```
$pdo= new PDO ( "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", 
                                                $username, $password, 
                                                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8;SET time_zone = 'UTC'") );
```

Here is the code If that might help

```
try {

    $statement = $pdo->prepare ( $sql );
    $statement->execute(); //exception on this line
    $result =  $statement->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    $statement->closeCursor();
    unset($statement);
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    sqlDie("Error: ", $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), array('exception' => $e));
}
```

**My System Configurations**

```
Windows 7
PHP 5.4.12
MySQL 5.6.12
Apache 2.4.4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing time zone after connecting to database using "set time\_zone = ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560881/changing-time-zone-after-connecting-to-database-using-set-time-zone)

Comment: I followed the same link to configure time zone. but it gives me error

Comment: Can you give some more code and php version?

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic way to set MySQL timezone depends on PHP timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$time_offset = date('P',time()); // +00:00
$pdo->query("SET time_zone='$time_offset';");
```