# How to set time_zone using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a connection using PDO that arrow `SET NAMES UTF8`:

```
$options = [ PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8" ];
```

But I would add the `SET time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo'`. But in all the ways I've tried it I get an Exception!

This is my connection class:

//Conexão usando objeto PDO Singleton Pattern

```
/** @var PDO */
private static $connect = null;

/**
 * Conecta com o banco de dados com o pattern singleton
 * Retorna um objeto PDO!
 */
private static function Conectar(){

    try {

        Setup::checkLocal();

        if(self::$connect == null) {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.Setup::$host.';dbname='.Setup::$base;
            $options = [ PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8; SET time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo'" ];
            self::$connect = new PDO($dsn, Setup::$user, Setup::$pass, $options);
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'PDOException: erro ao conectar ao banco de dados.';
        //PHPErro($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
        die;
    }

    self::$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //self::$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);

    return self::$connect;
}

/** Retorna um objeto PDO Singleton Pattern */
public static function getConn(){
    return self::Conectar();
}

public static function prepareQuery($query, $params){

    $preparedQuery = self::getConn()->prepare($query);
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $preparedQuery->bindValue($key, $value);
    }

    $preparedQuery->execute();
    $result = $preparedQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    self::$connect = null;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried "SET NAMES UTF8;SET time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing time zone after connecting to database using "set time\_zone = ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560881/changing-time-zone-after-connecting-to-database-using-set-time-zone)

Answer (score -2):

This may help you. try it!

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampletable', 
'exampleuser', 
'examplepassw', 
[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8;SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'"]);
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it gives me the following error: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.' in ..."

Comment: If I only use: [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8"] it works. But using [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8;SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'"] 
does not work

Comment: it won't work if you are executing more than one query at a time. Could you please show me some of your code.

Comment: The MySQL client protocol doesn't allow more than one query to be "in progress." That is, you've executed a query and you've fetched some of the results, but not all -- then you try to execute a second query. If the first query still has rows to return, the second query gets an error.